# How can we change date format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to change date format in mysql.I tried  this code

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(mydate, '%d.%m.%y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

But its not hep me.

My date comes from as string like this:

```
DD-MM-YYYY
```

I want to change it to this:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

How can I achive this with mysql?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share the full query?

Comment: Dates don't have a format. Any format you see is applied by the SQL client you are using. Check the manual of your SQL client if you can change the default date display format.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : your comment seems a valid answer to me

Answer (score 0):

Would:

```
STR_TO_DATE(mydate, '%y.%m.%d')
```

work then because when your are creating the date from the string you are implicitly giving it a format. Then just call it in a different format.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT str_to_date(table_column_name,'%d-%m-%Y') FROM `table_name`
```